# no php.ini and using default sample breaks functionality

Tags: php, openssl, ini

I'm just starting out with PHP and my first task is to handle requests to a website by sending retrieved form data to a specified email address.

I've made a simple contact.php file which is called by the Submit button on the form. The data is being retrieved, and I have processed it with the following code:

```
<?php 

require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$errors = '';
$myemail = 'randomtext@gmail.com';
$mypassword = 'randomtext';

if(empty($_POST['fname'])  ||
   empty($_POST['lname']) ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['subject']) ||
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required!";
}

$name = $_POST['fname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = 'De : ' . $name . '\n Concerning : ' . $_POST['subject'] . 
'\n\n' . $_POST['message']  ;
$subject = 'Query from website : ' . $_POST['subject'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail-> isSMTP();
$mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail-> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail-> SMTPHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail-> SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail-> Port ='465';
$mail-> isHTML();
$mail-> UserName=$myemail;
$mail-> Password=$mypassword;   
$mail-> SetFrom = $myemail;
$mail-> Subject = $subject;
$mail-> AddAddress($myemail);
$mail -> Body = $message;

if( empty($errors))
{
    $mail -> Send();
}
else
print $errors;

?>
```

The mail is not being sent and the debugger throws this error:
Extension missing: openssl

So I read elsewhere here that I needed to comment out the line extension=openssl in the PHP.ini file
However, I don't have a PHP.ini file anywhere on my windows installation.
http://localhost/phpinfp.php says that this file is in c:\Windows but there is no such file there.

I have got two files in my c:\PHP directory called php.ini-development and php.ini-production. However when I rename the first of these to php.ini and uncomment the line extension=openssl (restarting IIS afterwards) then PHP completely fails to function and calling contact.php generates a 500 error.

So, basically I need to either find what PHP.ini is really being used and edit that or find what line(s) in the development/production files are causing PHP to break and edit those.

It's php 7.2.4 on Windows 7

Comment: How did that PHP version came onto your Windows computer? How came the webserver you're using onto your Windows computer? This is all very much related to PHP configuration for which it is important to learn more about how PHP is installed and configured so far on your system. Consider that it takes some time to setup and round the edges when setting up PHP and a webserver for the first time.

Comment: I just installed the most recent PHP version available for 64-bit Windows 7, extracted to c:\PHP.  I enabled IIS in Windows control panel and configured it with the help of a tutorial online to use PHP.

Comment: Please follow the installation instructions given for your PHP install. One part it covers is the operation to enable the php.ini file. Part of it is as well (at least I highly recommend that to your) to go through all the settings in the ini file. It's fairly well commented also w/ links into the manual. If you take shortcuts when setting up a whole PHP webserver installation please don't wonder too much if sometihng just does not work.

Comment: Thanks. After a while of modifying the sample PHP production ini I got openssl enabled. Gmail is rejecting the connection from my locally hosted web server now, so I've advanced slightly.